# Unable to insert record into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Hi I am trying to insert data into mysql database upon a click of a button which name is 'request' button. However I can't do that and an error keeps popping up. You can scroll below for both the code and the error and there is a picture below showing the columns in my database.

Code here:

```
private void RequestButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        String type = txttype.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String name = txtname.getText();
        String quantity = txtquantity.getText();
        
        try {
            // String query = "INSERT INTO `orders`(`id`, `itemtype`, `itemname`, `quantity_ordered`, `userid`, `status`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/restock", "root", "password");
            pst = con1.prepareStatement("insert into orders (itemtype, itemname, quantity_ordered) values(?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1, type);
            pst.setString(2, name);
            pst.setString(3, quantity); 
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item has been requested");
              
            // Set the textfields to empty upon button click
            txttype.setSelectedIndex(-1);
            txtname.setText("");
            txtquantity.setText("");
            txttype.requestFocus();
           
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Error:

```
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Aug 09, 2020 3:04:50 AM pleasework.usermainpage RequestButtonActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'userid' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at pleasework.usermainpage.RequestButtonActionPerformed(usermainpage.java:382)
    at pleasework.usermainpage.access$400(usermainpage.java:24)
    at pleasework.usermainpage$5.actionPerformed(usermainpage.java:211)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Image on mysql database: (The records are already pre-added beforehand, only problem here is when I try to insert a new record, an error occurs and it does not get sent to the database. Another thing to take note of is that userid is a foreign key.)

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about MySQL but from the message it seems `userid` is a `not null` column and you are not passing any value for it.

Comment: Try passing value of userid column or set a default value for that column or make it nullable.

Comment: You obviously have a field named `userid` in your table but your insert query does not provide a value for that field and there is no default value defined. So either define a default value for the column (for instance an autoincremented value) or provide the value with your insert query

Comment: @derpirscher noted, I might try auto-increment on this then, and update you if its working

Answer (score 0):

i think the column `userid` is `required` or `not_null` or something similar that requires you to always have default value. The solution for this is either modify the table to include default value(or make the column `nullable`) or pass data into your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You're NOT providing any value for `userid` field. Change your query to something like this and provide a value for `userid` column.

```
   pst = con1.prepareStatement("insert into orders (userid, itemtype, itemname, quantity_ordered) values(?,?,?,?)");
```

If `userid` needs to be `NULL` in this case and that's why it's not included in your query, then you need to change your table to allow `NULL` in `userid` column so that your original query can work as intended.

Comment: Because userid is a foreign key and I don't see any reason by providing a value through inserting, can I change the settings of userid to null on its ON DELETE and ON UPDATE settings?

Comment: @JacksonEtherchainStake I don't understand the question. You can make your foreign key nullable but you need to provide a value for it. IF you don't want to porvide a value in INSERTS, don't include it in the INSERT statement (and make sure the column is NULLable)